# r: Convert list of matrices to a data frame

Tags: r

I ran a `foreach` loop to build a list of 100 matrices.  The output of each loop is one 7x12 matrix.  Now, I want to create a scatterplot the last two columns of each of those matrices using ggplot2.  To do this, I figure that I need to convert the list into one big `data.frame` that would come out to 700x12.  Other posters have solved this for a list of vectors but I don't see one that works for my situation.  Here is what I have tried:

```
as.data.frame(matrix(t(unlist(myList)), ncol=12)))
rbind(myList[1:100])
```

Comment: You could try `library(data.table);rbindlist(lapply(myList, as.data.frame))`

Comment: @why not `as.data.table`? :p

Comment: @MichaelChirico  Yes, that would be better

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you could use:

```
Reduce( rbind.data.frame, myList[1:100] )
```

Comment: this worked great when myList contained 100 matrices.  Is there any reason why this command has been running for an hour after I increased myList to 270k matrices?

Comment: I'm not an expert at R performance, but I think that is because `Reduce` finds processes then `myList[1]` and `myList[2]` and writes them to memory, than `rbind`s `myList[3]` to it and writes it to memory, and so on. With 100 matrices this might be such a big problem, but for 270 000 it is... If you know in advance how many rows of the `data.frame` you need, you can pre-create it and fill it in with a loop. This will save you a lot of memory and possibly performance.

Answer (score 1):

In your foreach loop, why don't you convert the matrix to a dataframe? If x is your matrix, you can just add this to the end:

```
data.frame(x)
```

Then you can just use `rbind(myList[1:100])` as you have been.

Comment: I tried that but foreach loop takes hours to run instead of 11 minutes.

Comment: How odd. Try `as.data.frame(x)`